# How to use JsonSerializerSettings and UseSnakeCasePropertyNames

Tags: c#, json, rest, mapping, marketo

I need to map some fields from the Ambassador API to C#.

The API output looks like this:

```
"data": {
    "ambassadors": [],
    "company": {
        "company_name": "Trupanion Managers USA, Inc.",
        "company_url": "",
        "company_email": "gina.pizzalato@trupanion.com",
        "point_name": "points",
        "outgoing_email": "",
        "avatar_url": "https://ambassador-api.s3.amazonaws.com/generic_avatar.png"
    }
```

And the C# looks like:

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string CompanyUrl { get; set; }

    public string CompanyEmail { get; set; }

    public string PointName { get; set; }

    public string OutgoingEmail { get; set; }

    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Doug said to look at Marketo and use the PostIocBootstrapConfiguration to configure the JsonSettings, like so:

```
this.jsonSerializerSettings.SetFor<MarketoTokenResponse>(new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                UseSnakeCasePropertyNames = true
            });
```

but it's not working.

Is there more to it?
Is there an app.config or a Reference I need to add?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's "not working"? What output do you get?

Comment: Is that class [`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm)?  Is your problem that your code does not compile?  If so, what compilation errors do you get?  If you can [edit] your question to include this information as well as a full [mcve] that tells us how to reproduce your problem, we're much more likely to be able to help.